# How to implement an XML-RPC server in AS3 (Flash or AIR runtime)?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, listener, xml-rpc

I'm looking for a good **XML-RPC server implementation** to be included as part of an existing **Flash+AS3 application** in order to be notified on events by a client.

The ideal implementation should be well written, **documented**, **reliable** and **encapsulated** in order to be easily and cleanly wrapped.

***EDIT:***
I'm working on porting the app on **Adobe AIR runtime**, will this execution environment bypass the listening socket limitation? If yes, any doc about this issue?

Answer (score 3):

Well, XML-RPC specifies using HTTP as transport protocol. Since Flash can not listen on sockets (only connect to them) I do not believe it would be directly possible to create an actual XML-RPC server with Flash.

That being said, a client is definately possible, and has been done a couple of times:

http://code.google.com/p/as3-rpclib

http://danielmclaren.net/2007/08/03/xmlrpc-for-actionscript-30-free-library

The second one is a port of an AS1/2 library.

Comment: Thanks for the info regarding the impossibility of socket listening in flash (can I have a link to some official doc for this argument?). + 1 for this. Regarding the client I thank you for the links, but my app already implements xml-rpc client successfully. Thanks again

Comment: All of the networking support that is in Flash is part of the flash.net package. Here's a link to the docs for the most recent version of that package: http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/gumbo/langref/flash/net/package-detail.html

Comment: Also, I have heard word that the next version of AIR may be able to listen on ports (not sure if it's TCP, UDP or both though) but it is not currently available as of AIR 1.5.2.

Answer (score 0):

I found [this article](http://blog.comtaste.com/2008/09/monitoring_the_connection_agai.html) talking about a [SocketMonitor](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/air/net/SocketMonitor.html) framework.

In the example given it uses this piece of code

```
var myIstance = 
   Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/server-socket;1"]
   .createInstance(Components.interfaces.nsIServerSocket);
```

That really resemble to a listening socket server, but I'm afraid it is only a good implementation of a poll mechanism.